# Sitecore Federated Experience Manager issue on view list and add new website

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-fxm

I would like to use Federated Experience Manager on my test server but I see a error with not clear description and no information in logs files,

When I try to add a new website I see next error in console:

```
OPTIONS http://myhost.com/sitecore/api/ssc/domainmatcher/service 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

when I tried to open list of websites

```
http://myhost.com/sitecore/api/ssc/domainmatcher/service/DomainMatcher/QueryAll?search=&sorting=aName&skip=0&top=999 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Log:

> jQuery.ajaxTransport.options.send @   jquery-2.1.1.js:8623
>   jQuery.extend.ajax    @   jquery-2.1.1.js:8152
>   Sitecore.Speak.Definitions.Models.ControlModel.extend.getItems    @   CustomSearchDataSource.js:87
>   Sitecore.Speak.Definitions.Models.ControlModel.extend.refresh @   CustomSearchDataSource.js:48
>   (anonymous function)  @   DomainDashboard.js:39
>   triggerEvents @   backbone.1.0.0.js:203
>   Backbone.Events.trigger   @   backbone.1.0.0.js:146
>   _sc.Definitions.App.extend.initialized    @   DomainDashboard.js:68 Speak.Definitions.App.Backbone.Model.extend.run   @   sitecore-1.0.2.js:685
>   _.extend.load.runPageCode @   sitecore-1.0.2.js:986 (anonymous function)  @   sitecore-1.0.2.js:1010 context.execCb   @   require.js:1650
>   Module.check  @   require.js:866 Module.enable    @   require.js:1143
>   Module.init   @   require.js:774 (anonymous function) @   require.js:1416

response message a similar in both cases  `Message: "An error has occurred."`

what could be an issue ?
it is working on my local PC with sitecore 8 SP5 .

Comment: I reinstalled sitecore and check mongodb, and it is looks fine now.